# How to turn a matrix of nested vectors into a vector of nested vectors

Tags: matrix, vector, data-conversion, apl

I am producing a matrix of pairs (= nested vectors) like so:

```
x←⍳10
y←⍳10
x∘.,y
```

But for further processing I need to have the pairs in one vector of pairs. If I apply ravel:

```
,/x∘.,y
```

then the pairs are not anymore nested.
How to transform the matrix into a vector and retain the nested pairs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to [ravel](https://apl.wiki/ravel) the matrix:

```
,x∘.,y
```

This reshapes the matrix into a vector containing the same elements in [ravel order](https://apl.wiki/Ravel_order).